# Creating nameservers via BIND9

Tags: networking, server, ssh, dns

So I have a VPS and I need to create nameservers that I can use with my domain registrar to have my domain viewable.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and I am accessing ssh via putty.

This is what I have done:

Run command `apt-get install bind9 bind9utils bind9-doc`

Defined the DNZ zone `nano /etc/bind/named.conf.local` and insert the following code:

```
zone " MYDOMAIN.COM" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/ MYDOMAIN.COM";
 };
```

I opened the file `nano /etc/bind/MYDOMAIN.COM` and insert the following:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     ns1. MYDOMAIN.COM. root. MYDOMAIN.COM. (
        2022042501  ;Serial
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
@       IN  NS          ns1. MYDOMAIN.COM.
@       IN  NS          ns2. MYDOMAIN.COM.
ns1     IN  A           VPS IP ADDRESS (THE ONE I USE TO LOGIN WITH)
ns2     IN  A           VPS IP ADDRESS (THE ONE I USE TO LOGIN WITH)
@       IN  A           VPS IP ADDRESS (THE ONE I USE TO LOGIN WITH)
```

Ran these commands:
`chmod -R 755 /etc/bind`
`chown -R bind:bind /etc/bind`

and then I restart the DNS server
`systemctl restart bind9`

Did I miss a step? For the ns1 and ns2 ip address, should I have used the ip from my VPS control panel instead of what I use to login via ssh?

[image]

After doing all of the above I get the error with my domain registrar

> This is likely caused by the entered NameServers not being created
> yet. Please check the spelling of the NameServers you entered as well
> as checking to make sure they have been created at the applicable
> registry.

Comment: Netmask is wrong, IP and Gateway are incompatible - whats the point of giving this information when you randomize it? When the server is running you can test with `dig mydomain.com @127.0.0.1` Also you should have at least two (different) nameservers.

Comment: Yes, I randomize it but I am asking if the template setup for the bind was correct or not. As in for ns1 and ns2 I should use the nameserver (100.100.100.12 and 100.100.100.13) and 64.23.156.162 for the final @ ip address.

Comment: When you remove the spaces in front of " MYDOMAIN.COM" the zonefile looks ok. Keep in mind that when using nameservers in your own domain, you need glue-records. You can use the `100.100.100.*` nameservers if they are configured to serve your zone and accept updates from your IP. Then you also need to set `allow-transfer` in the bind-config.